# Passing 2 Variables from 2 Diffreent Screen to 1 Screen

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing

I have Home() , Category(), Region() classes

To add category I navigate to Category() and to add region I navigate to Region()

I want pass the values of cat inside Category and the value of city inside Region to Home screen, but I receive this error:

```
Compiler message:
lib/Screens/regions.dart:32:95: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home(city)));
```

Here is Home Screen:

```
 class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  final String sRegion;
  final String sCategory;

  Home(this.sRegion,this.sCategory, {Key key}):super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Text(cat + city),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Category Screen:

```
 class Category extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _CategoryState createState() => _CategoryState();
}

class _CategoryState extends State<Category> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 String cat = 'General';
return Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: FlatButton( onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home(cat)));
          },),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Region Screen:

```
     class Region extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _RegionState createState() => _RegionState();
}

class _RegionState extends State<Region> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 String city = 'London';
return Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: FlatButton( onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home(city)));
          },),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Home` has two positional parameters that are mandatory (`sRegion` and `sCategory`). Those are not optional and you have to provide them.

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, 
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home(city, cat)));
```

Notice that I added `cat` to `Home` constructor. If any of those parameters is optional you need to rewrite the constructor signature.

If you want to make any of those parameters optional, convert them to named arguments

```
Home({this.sRegion,this.sCategory, Key key}):super(key: key);
```

Comment: Yes both are optional.. Can you tell me please how to modify the constructor signature?

Comment: @AlexAli: updated my answer, you need to convert them into named arguments

Comment: I did it but now I received another error: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home(city, cat)))

Comment: @AlexAli `AddAd(sRegion: sRegion, sCategory: sCategory)`

Comment: It worked but when the 'city' is added and I go to add 'cat' it resets city back to default values and vice versa